Can't render an SVG with a hole inside a path (location icon)
I'm trying to render an SVG icon for a location with PixiJS. This is the SVG string that I'm using:
<svg width="28" height="40" viewBox="0 0 28 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
// <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14 0C6.26 0 0 6.26 0 14C0 24.5 14 40 14 40C14 40 28 24.5 28 14C28 6.26 21.74 0 14 0ZM14 19C11.24 19 9 16.76 9 14C9 11.24 11.24 9 14 9C16.76 9 19 11.24 19 14C19 16.76 16.76 19 14 19Z" />
// </svg>

It renders correctly in Figma, I tried with many different icons, but the issue with PixiJS is the same:

The hole in middle doesn't render as a cutout. I tried adding fill-rule="evenodd", tried with nonzero too - no luck. In any case it should work without modifying the SVG file. Here is how I'm drawing it:
o.graphic = new Graphics()
this.#artboard.addChild(o.graphic)
o.graphic.svg(pinSVG)
o.graphic.stroke({ color: 'black', width: 2 })
o.graphic.fill('red')

I also tried loading it as a Texture and the hole renders fine, but then I can't modify the stroke, etc.

PixiJS doesn't have perfect 1:1 support for svg, and this is one example

@BlobKat There really is no solution? Very sad

You need to correct path directions for the compound path to get rid of the fill-rule dependency. See "Converting an svg with fill-rule="evenodd" to fill-rule="nonzero"" or "auto colour fill when Generate Font from svg figma icon using icomoon". Also there are some figma plugins you could use like "Vector Path Editor" or "SVG Auto Fix Path Directions"
